# Как правильно сформировать массив js

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, объекты

Есть массив объектов

```
0: 'tkm': [0.18, 1.29, 0.11, 4.1],
1: 'tsm': [0.14, 1.21, 0.15, 4.5],
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы хотел его отформатировать и привести к виду:

```
0: ['tkm', 0.18, 1.29, 0.11, 4.1],
1: ['tsm', 0.14, 1.21, 0.15, 4.5],
```

Тем самым перенести ключ в значение.
Пытаюсь реализовать это, но у меня числа в текст как одно значение выводятся

```
          let refactor= $.map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(key)), (value, i) => {
                $.extend(value, {name: i})
          }

          console.log( [String(Object.keys(key))+','+refactor] );
```

Уже сижу над этой глупостью много времени, прошу помощи.

Comment: let o = {tkm:[0,1,2,3,4]};
o[Object.keys(o)[0]].unshift(Object.keys(o)[0]);
o = o.tkm;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотели вот так?:

```js
let arr = [
  { 'tkm': [0.18, 1.29, 0.11, 4.1] },
  { 'tsm': [0.14, 1.21, 0.15, 4.5] },
]

arr = arr.map((e, i, a) => {
  let key = Object.keys(a[i])[0]
  return [key].concat(e[key])
})


console.log(arr)
```

#### Объяснение

Через метод `map` в callback'е мы передаём аргументы `e` (Текущий элемент), `i` (Текущий индекс элемента) и `a` (Текущий массив), дальше бы берём ключ из отталкиваясь от текущего индекса и сохраняем  его в переменную, и возвращаем массив с ключом, который соединённый с текущим массивом и так на каждой интерации.

Comment: Да спасибо ) вы помогли более лаконично и правильно, я скорее возьму это для реализации к себе, т.к. мой метод более "костыльный"

Comment: @ПашаХарченко вот и отлично) Тогда нажмите на галочку слева от ответа (действия принятия ответа как правильный), вам не тяжело, а мне приятно))

Answer (score 0):

```
let refactor= $.map(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(key)), (value, i) => 
$.extend(value, { name: i }));

let obj = refactor;
obj.unshift(Object.keys(key)[0]);
```

Comment: Сделайте это сниппетом, непонятно работает ли предложенный вами ответ.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{'tkm': [0.18, 1.29, 0.11, 4.1]},{'tsm': [0.14, 1.21, 0.15, 4.5]}];
let new_arr = arr.map(el => [Object.keys(el)[0],...Object.values(el)[0]])
console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: А зачем вызывать Object.values(), когда уже известен ключ (`Object.keys(el)[0]`)? Это ведь лишняя нагрузка.